# Custom authentication with spring-security and reactive spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm having a custom authentication scheme. I'm having a REST endpoint that has `userId` in http uri path and `token` in http header. I would like to check that such request is perform by valid user with valid token. Users and tokens are stored in mongo collection.

I don't know in which class I should authorize user.

My `SecurityConfig`:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {

    val build = http
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .logout().disable()
        .authenticationManager(CustomReactiveAuthenticationManager())
        .securityContextRepository(CustomServerSecurityContextRepository())
        .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/api/measurement/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
        .anyExchange().permitAll().and()

    return build.build()
  }

  @Bean
  fun userDetailsService(): MapReactiveUserDetailsService {
    val user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
        .username("sampleDeviceIdV1")
        .password("foo")
        .roles("USER")
        .build()

    return MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user)
  }
}
```

My `ServerSecurityContextRepository`:

```
class CustomServerSecurityContextRepository : ServerSecurityContextRepository {

  override fun load(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<SecurityContext> {
    val authHeader = exchange.request.headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)
    val path = exchange.request.uri.path


    return if (path.startsWith("/api/measurement/") && authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith(prefix = "Bearer ")) {
      val deviceId = path.drop(17)

      val authToken = authHeader.drop(7)
      val auth = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(deviceId, authToken)
      Mono.just(SecurityContextImpl(auth))
    } else {
      Mono.empty()
    }
  }

  override fun save(exchange: ServerWebExchange?, context: SecurityContext?): Mono<Void> {
    return Mono.empty()
  }
}
```

Two questions arise:

1. Is `ServerSecurityContextRepository` good place to obtain username and token from exchange - or there is a better place to do it?
2. Where should I perform authentication (check token and username against mongo collection)? 
   My custom `AuthenticationManager` does not get called anywhere. Should I do everything inside `ServerSecurityContextRepository` or perform user and token validation inside `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`? Or maybe other class would be even more suitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that some tutorials on the web are plain wrong.

I've managed to configure everything using following code:

```
class DeviceAuthenticationConverter : Function<ServerWebExchange, Mono<Authentication>> {
  override fun apply(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<Authentication> {
    val authHeader: String? = exchange.request.headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)
    val path: String? = exchange.request.uri.path

    return when {
      isValidPath(path) && isValidHeader(authHeader) -> Mono.just(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(path?.drop(17), authHeader?.drop(7)))
      else -> Mono.empty()
    }
  }

  private fun isValidPath(path: String?) = path != null && path.startsWith(API_MEASUREMENT)

  private fun isValidHeader(authHeader: String?) = authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith(prefix = "Bearer ")

}
```

And config:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

  companion object {
    const val API_MEASUREMENT = "/api/measurement/"
    const val API_MEASUREMENT_PATH = "$API_MEASUREMENT**"
    const val DEVICE = "DEVICE"
    const val DEVICE_ID = "deviceId"
  }

  @Bean
  fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity, authenticationManager: ReactiveAuthenticationManager) =
      http
          .httpBasic().disable()
          .formLogin().disable()
          .csrf().disable()
          .logout().disable()
          .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(API_MEASUREMENT_PATH).hasRole(DEVICE)
          .anyExchange().permitAll().and().addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager), AUTHENTICATION).build()

  @Bean
  fun userDetailsService(tokenRepository: TokenRepository) = MongoDeviceTokenReactiveUserDetailsService(tokenRepository)

  @Bean
  fun tokenRepository(template: ReactiveMongoTemplate, passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder) = MongoTokenRepository(template, passwordEncoder)

  @Bean
  fun tokenFacade(tokenRepository: TokenRepository) = TokenFacade(tokenRepository)

  @Bean
  fun authManager(userDetailsService: ReactiveUserDetailsService) = UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(userDetailsService)

  private fun authenticationWebFilter(reactiveAuthenticationManager: ReactiveAuthenticationManager) =
      AuthenticationWebFilter(reactiveAuthenticationManager).apply {
        setAuthenticationConverter(DeviceAuthenticationConverter())
        setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(
            ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, API_MEASUREMENT_PATH)
        )
      }

  @Bean
  fun passwordEncoder() = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()
}
```